# True or False? $\int\limits_0^2(x-x^3)dx$ represents the area under the curve $y=x-x^3$ from 0 to 2.

Tags: integration

True or False?

$\int\limits_0^2(x-x^3)dx$ represents the area under the curve $y=x-x^3$ from 0 to 2.

I said true but my textbook says false. Why?

(Stewart: Concepts and Contexts p424 q13)

Comment: plot the curve $y=x-x^3$ between $0$ and $2$ and define the 'Area'

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: or "*under*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textbook says that $\int\limits_0^2(x-x^3)dx$ does not represent the area **under** the curve $y=x-x^3$ because at $x=1$ the curve crosses the x-axis and becomes negative. Therefore, the area between the curve and the x-axis from 1 to 2 is not **under** the curve.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your function becomes negative. It is true if you consider that when $f$ is negative, the area should be counted negatively as well.

Comment: @ahorn we don't sit and wait for the questions (a lot of very clever guys probably have a lot of interesting jobs/lives) but if we have a large population of people on the forum and a question (a very easy one at that) pops up, then of course you will get a quick answer. The fact you found your answer so quickly suggests that you could of saved your time posting and answered :). So remember next time that if your problem is something that you could answer with some more thought and you wanted to answer it yourself then don't post it.